# Eclipse Helios 3.6.0 hangs while installing Egit

Tags: eclipse-plugin, egit, eclipse-3.6, eclipse-marketplace

I am trying to install Egit on my eclipse using market place.

The problem i am facing is that the installation gets stuck at 49%. I waited for almost 2 hours yesterday but still the installation did not happen. Has anyone faced any such problems before?

Is there a manual way i can install Egit. i.e. by downloading a package and then installing. I am using windows 7 machine.

Can anyone please guide me on this issue?

P.s: I have gone through the previous asked questions, and i do not have many other sites being used as download pages.(So it is not slow due to loading of many sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing EGit from the following update site?

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

You can use this update site by going to:

*Help* > *Install New Software...*

and enter the URL in the **Work with:** text box

Comment: I have done that,it does not work. It still gets hanged at 49%.

Comment: I guess  this should and will work in normal conditions. As for my problem it was solved by using "eclipse 3.7.o Indigo". I dont know what the problem for Helios was.

Answer (score 2):

What has worked for me is the following:

1. Find a mirror in your country, in my case was http://eclipse.tsl.gr/egit/updates-1.3/
2. Go to install software and paste the mirror url in the work with box and select the packages you wish to install
3. This is the solver: un check "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

I am not sure whether it helped but I also updated Java to latest version while trying to install EGit on Helios.

Comment: cool! solved my problem too...I am using Eclipse 3.6 or Helios

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the OP with all marketplace plugins. My downloads of plugins consistently got stuck on 48% or 49% and would eventually time out.

In my case, I solved the problem by turning off my antivirus and then downloading plugins.

While my antivirus was turned off, I did not browse the web. I also ran antivirus and anti malware scans afterwards.